# How to solve this List<dynamic> type error in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, types

I am very new to flutter and dart. Trying to return a list from this future that pulls data from an api but I keep getting this error. Someone here helped me solve a similar error by casting to a list because I was calling map function on an array that returns an iterable but in this case here I'm not sure what needs to be done.

```
type List<dynamic> is not a subtype of type FutrueOr<ListCity>>
```

Data is received like below:

```
{
 "data": {
        "127287": {
            "Feature_int_id": "127287",
            "Admin1_str_code": "US06",
            "Country_str_code": "US",
            "Feature_str_name": "Acampo",
            "Feature_dec_lat": "38.194",
            "Feature_dec_lon": "-121.25"
        },
        "116496": {
            "Feature_int_id": "116496",
            "Admin1_str_code": "US06",
            "Country_str_code": "US",
            "Feature_str_name": "Acton",
            "Feature_dec_lat": "34.49",
            "Feature_dec_lon": "-118.22"
        },
        "124284": {
            "Feature_int_id": "124284",
            "Admin1_str_code": "US06",
            "Country_str_code": "US",
            "Feature_str_name": "Adelanto",
            "Feature_dec_lat": "34.665",
            "Feature_dec_lon": "-117.512"
        },
}
```

Below is the code for future:

```
Future<List<City>> fetchCitiesByProvince(provinceCode) async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.https('localhost/msd', 'api/cities/' + provinceCode));
  final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
  final dataMap =  responseJson['data'];

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
 
    List citiesList = [];
    for (var city in dataMap.keys) {
      if (dataMap[city]['Admin1_str_code'] == provinceCode) {
        citiesList.add(
          {
            'cityCode': dataMap[city]['Feature_int_id'],
            'cityName': dataMap[city]['Feature_str_name']
          }
        );
      }
    }
    return citiesList;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load cities');
  }
}
```

City Class:

```
class City {
  final String cityCode;
  final String cityName;

  City({@required this.cityCode, @required this.cityName});

  factory City.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {

    return City(
      cityCode: json['Feature_int_id'],
      cityName: json['Feature_str_name']
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return `List<City>` in your method. So, change the following code:

```
List citiesList = [];
```

to

```
List<City> citiesList = [];
```

--- UPDATE ---

You need to user your City constructor or factory to generate the item from json like this:

```
City.fromJson(dataMap[city]);

// Or

City(cityCode: dataMap[city]['Feature_int_id'],
        cityName: dataMap[city]['Feature_str_name']
    );
```

Here the updated sample code:

```
Future<List<City>> fetchCitiesByProvince(provinceCode) async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.https('localhost/msd', 'api/cities/' + provinceCode));
  final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
  final dataMap =  responseJson['data'];

  List<City> citiesList = [];

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    
    for (var city in dataMap.keys) {
      if (dataMap[city]['Admin1_str_code'] == provinceCode) {
        citiesList.add(City.fromJson(dataMap[city]));
      }
    }
  } else {

    throw Exception('Failed to load cities');
    // either throwing an error or return empty list.
  }

  return citiesList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried that already and it does not work. I still get the same error when I run the app but before running it I can see an issue in the code highlighted in red and on hovering over it says: The argument type 'Map<String, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'City'

Comment: Added code for my City class above in my question

Comment: @sayayin: You need to use City constructor or factory. See my updated answer.

Comment: So I'm thinking I'm thinking I was not supposed to make any changes in city class but just the one you posted above?  citiesList.add(City.fromJson(dataMap[city])); With this I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Spoke too quick, actually its working. I was missing the change where citiesList is defined. It was still List citiesList = []; insteasd of List<City> citiesList = [];
All good now, thank you!